# How to access Set nested in List?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the data:

```
{'Let It Go', 'Idina Menzel'},
{'Hakuna Matata', 'Nathan Lane'},
{'A Whole New World', 'Naomi Scott'},
{'Under the Sea', 'Samuel E. Wright'}
```

How should I declare and use this data if I want to store it?

```
var list = const [
    {'Let It Go', 'Idina Menzel'},
    {'Hakuna Matata', 'Nathan Lane'},
    {'A Whole New World', 'Naomi Scott'},
    {'Under the Sea', 'Samuel E. Wright'}
];
```

When I declare this and use it like `list[0][1]`, I get an error.

Comment: you will call by value and key

Answer (score -1):

Using the [elementAt](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Iterable/elementAt.html) method of [Set](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Set-class.html) class.

```dart
list[0].elementAt(1)
```

---

If you prefer to use lists instead, then consider this method

```dart
var list = const [
    ['Let It Go', 'Idina Menzel'],
    ['Hakuna Matata', 'Nathan Lane'],
    ['A Whole New World', 'Naomi Scott'],
    ['Under the Sea', 'Samuel E. Wright']
  ];
```

and get element as `list[0][1]`

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you one more question? If you want to mix data types like ['let it go', 'idina menzel, 10], how do i declare it?

Comment: you can use dynamic. ```List<List<dynamic>> list = [
    ['let it go', 'idina menzel', 10],
    ['let it go', 'idina menzel', 10],
    ['let it go', 'idina menzel', 10]
  ];```